# PopulateTableview via Structs & Arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, tableview, xcode7

```
    struct Games {
    var GameName        :   String
    var GameCheats      :   [Cheats]
}

struct Cheats {
    var CheatName           :   String
    var CheatCode           :   String
    var CheatDescription    :   String
}

let COD4 = Games(GameName: "Name", GameCheats: [Cheats(CheatName: "Cheat", CheatCode: "Code", CheatDescription: "Description")])
```

The above code is what i currently have in a swift file within my test project.
I am now trying to take values from above to populate a tableview, see below:

```
class GamesListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var ArrayOfGames = [COD4]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ArrayOfGames.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = ArrayOfGames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

But i am receiving an error:
" Cannot assign type value 'Games' to type 'String?' "

I am new to swift but do have experience in php, I'm seriously struggling to transfer my knowledge across :(

I appreciate any help.

Kindest regards
Rory

Answer (score 1):

Cell's `textLabel?.text` is of type `String`. You are trying to assign a `Game` to it:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = ArrayOfGames[indexPath.row]
```

You need to create a string from your `Game` object, describing your game. The simplest solution would be to use `name`:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = ArrayOfGames[indexPath.row].GameName
```

This would compile and run. Cell's label would correspond to the name of your game.

A more interesting description can be formed with a list of cheats:

```
let cheatList = ArrayOfGames[indexPath.row]
    .GameCheats
    .map { "\($0.CheatName): \($0.CheatCode) \($0.CheatDescription)" }
    .joinWithSeparator(", ")
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(ArrayOfGames[indexPath.row].GameName) \(cheatList)"
```

Comment: The list of cheats description is very interesting!
I will certainly keep that bit of code for future reference..
Thanks for the help.
If i could ask 1 more question? How would i go about passing cheat information onto a new tableview that is relevant to the parent game? I will use prepare for segue and set everything up ready, i just need to know how to pass the data.. Sorry for all the questions. Kindest regards Rory

Comment: @user1263909 In the prepare for segue you have access to the row on which the user clicked. Use the row to get `ArrayOfGames[selectedRow]` `Game` object. You also have access to the "details" view controller. Create a variable `currentGame: Game` in the detail controller, and set it to the selected game in prepare for segue.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayOfGames[indexPath.row]` returns a `Games` struct. You cannot assign that to the `text` property of a label (it expects a `String?`). I assume you meant to use the `GameName` property on your struct. For example:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = ArrayOfGames[indexPath.row].GameName
```

But more importantly, you should consider re-thinking your namings. A few conventions that you should follow are:

- Property & method names should begin with a lowercase letter, and follow `camelCase`
- Class, struct, enum & protocol names should begin with an uppercase letter and follow `CamelCase`
- Class and struct names should be singular unless they actually represent something plural (i.e not `Games` if it only represents a single game)
- You should avoid repeating the name of your struct in its properties (i.e `gameName` in your `Game` struct)
- You should avoid repeating the type of a property in its name if it already has a clear meaning (i.e `games`, not `arrayOfGames`)

Therefore a more conventional naming system for your code would look like this:

```
struct Game {
    var name : String
    var cheats : [Cheat]
}

struct Cheat {
    var name : String
    var code : String
    var description : String
}


class GamesListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var games = [game1, game2, game3, ... gameN]

    ...


   cell.textLabel?.text = games[indexPath.row].name
```

[Ray Wenderlich has a pretty nice Swift style guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide) that I'd recommend you have a look at.

Comment: Thank you for informing me as to the more conventional ways!
It works perfectly, can't believe it was something as simple as adding .name to indexpath.row lol.
If i could ask 1 more question?
How would i go about passing cheat information onto a new tableview that is relevant to the parent game?
I will use prepare for segue and set everything up ready, i just need to know how to pass the data..
Sorry for all the questions.

Kindest regards
Rory

Comment: @user1263909 Hi Rory, happy to help. I'm not entirely sure what you're having trouble with when passing your data to a new view controller – `prepareForSegue` is definitely the right way to go though. I would advise against conflating two questions into one post, so I would suggest you ask a new question about this. Although there are already [quite a lot of questions on this topic](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=swift%20passing%20data%20between%20view%20controllers%20site%3Astackoverflow.com), so make sure to do your research before asking!

Comment: Thank you, i will take your advice and snoop around first.
If i fail to find the answer i will create a new question and paste the link here to make things easier.

Thanks again

Comment: Hi, after searching i am just getting extremely confused :(
I really want to learn Swift and i am in the process of purchasing some manuals from Amazon.
I have created a new question that includes a dropbox link to my test project. here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100873/pass-data-from-struct-array-to-new-tableview-controller

If you are willing, would you be kind enough to just poke around inside it?
Thanks so much for your help!

Kind regards
Rory