# Pass data from struct array to new tableview controller

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, tableview

I am trying to pass data from my Cheats struct into a new tableviewcontroller to populate the new table with the relevant info.
I have done research but am new to swift.
I do have experience in php but transferring my knowledge is proving quite difficult...

In my prepare for segue class i receive a few errors:

Definition conflicts with previous value:

```
var DataPass = CheatsArray[indexPath.row]
```

Cannot assign value type 'String' to '[String]':

```
DestViewController.CheatsArray = DataPass.name
```

Here is a copy of my current 3 files

Structs and arrays:

```
struct Game {
    var name : String
    var cheats : [Cheat]
}

struct Cheat {
    var name : String
    var code : String
    var description : String
}

// Create Our Game Info And Cheats / Codes For Each Game!
//-------------------------------------------------------
let COD4 = Game(name: "Call Of Duty 4", cheats: [Cheat(name: "Cheat", code: "Code", description: "Description")])
let GTAV = Game(name: "Grand Theft Auto 5", cheats: [Cheat(name: "Cheat", code: "Code", description: "Description")])


// Place Our New Games Inside This Array!
//---------------------------------------
let ArrayOfGames = [COD4,GTAV]
```

GameListController:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class GamesListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var CheatsArray = [Game]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ArrayOfGames.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = ArrayOfGames[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CheatsListViewController

        let DataPass : Game
        var DataPass = CheatsArray[indexPath.row]
        DestViewController.CheatsArray = DataPass.name

    }

}
```

CheatListController:

```
class CheatsListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var CheatsArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return CheatsArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = CheatsArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }

}
```

Comment: Paste the relevant parts of your code into the question. At a minimum, show the structure you want to pass and your attempt at your prepareForSegue. Stack Overflow questions need to be self contained. Links to external projects are frowned upon because the links could break in the future and the question and answer should both be here together for future reference to help others.

Comment: Ah, i do apologise!
I will look at editing my question.
Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: Question edited, thanks again for letting me know :)

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because you defined DataPass twice, one row after another. You can't do that in the same scope. Change the name of one.

The second error is because you cannot assign value type 'String' to '[String]'. Just looking at *CheatsArray* and *name* variables, it's clear the first is an array and the second is most likely a string. You might want to *[append](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107)* the name to the array.